Does $\log(\log n)$ grow asymptotically slower than $\frac{\log n}{\log(\log n)}$?
I'm trying to understand the asymptotic growth of relationship between $\log(\log n)$ and $\frac{\log n}{\log(\log n)}$ as $n \to \infty$.
Specifically, I want to verify whether this statement is true or false:
$$\log(\log n) = O\left( \frac{\log n}{\log(\log n)} \right)$$
Could someone help confirm whether this is true or false?
Thank you for your insights!
I was initially confused because $(\log(\log n))^2$ appears to grow faster than $\log n$ for large $n$, but I suspect my intuition may be wrong.

Yes it is true. But when we say grow faster this is really an asymptotic statement. For fixed and reasonably sized values of $n$  a slower growing function may still be larger than a faster growing. Take 10^100 and O(n) as examples. The former doesn't grow at all.

Let $k=\log n$, so we are considering $\log k$ and $k/\log k$. We just need to calculate a simple limitation $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log k}{k/\log k}.$$ If the limitation is $0$ then $\log k=o(k/\log k)$. Thus $\log\log n=O(\log n/\log\log n)$.

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log k}{k/\log k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log^2 k}{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2\log k}{k}=0.$$


Can you explain the step $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log^2 k}{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2\log k}{k}$?

@KellyBundy I am assuming that the base of $\log$ is $e$. L'hospital method is applied to infer the step.

@KellyBundy the derivative of $\log^2 k$ is $2 \log k / k$.

@JohnKemeny yes but the derivative of $k$ is $1$, so the ratio of the derivatives is  $\frac{(2\log k) / k}{1} = \frac{2\log k}{k}$
